# How write extracted image to file object instead of to file system?

Tags: python, pdf, io, stream, pdfminer

I'm using the Python [pdfminer library](https://github.com/euske/pdfminer) to extract both text and images from a PDF. Since the [TextConverter class](https://github.com/euske/pdfminer/blob/master/pdfminer/converter.py#L156-L197) by default writes to `sys.stdout`, I used `StringIO` to catch the text as a variable as follows (see paste:

```
def extractTextAndImagesFromPDF(rawFile):
    laparams = LAParams()
    imagewriter = ImageWriter('extractedImageFolder/')    
    resourceManager = PDFResourceManager(caching=True)

    outfp = StringIO()  # Use StringIO to catch the output later.
    device = TextConverter(resourceManager, outfp, codec='utf-8', laparams=laparams, imagewriter=imagewriter)
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resourceManager, device)
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(rawFile, set(), maxpages=0, caching=True, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    device.close()    
    extractedText = outfp.getvalue()  # Get the text from the StringIO
    outfp.close()
    return extractedText
```

This works fine for the extracted text. What this function also does is extracting the images in the PDF and writing them to the `'extractedImageFolder/'`. This works also fine, but **I now want the images to be "written to" a file object instead of to the file system**, so that I can do some post processing on them.

The [ImageWriter class](https://github.com/euske/pdfminer/blob/master/pdfminer/image.py#L62-L122) defines a file (`fp = file(path, 'wb')`) and then writes to that. What I would like is that my `extractTextAndImagesFromPDF()` function can also return a list of file objects, instead of directly writing them to a file. I guess I also need to use `StringIO` for that, but I wouldn't know how. Partly also because the writing to file is happening within the pdfminer.

Does anybody know how I can return a list of file objects instead of writing the images to the file system? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hack to allow you to provide a file pointer of your own to write to:

```
   # add option in aguments to supply your own file pointer
   def export_image(self, image, fp=None):
        ...
        # change this line:
        # fp = file(path, 'wb')
        # add instead:
        fp = fp if fp else file(path, 'wb')
        ...
        # and this line:
        # return name
        # add instead:
        return (fp, name,) if fp else name
```

Now you would need to use:

```
# create file-like object backed by string buffer
fp = stringIO.stringIO()
image_fp, name = export_image(image, fp)
```

and your image should be stored in `fp`.

Note that the behaviour to `export_image`, if it was used elsewhere, remains the same.

Comment: Thank you! There are 2 problems though. First: I would need to fork the pdfminer lib, where I would preferably like to do it without forking. And 2nd; if I do decide to fork pdfminer, `export_image()` could return the fp, but `export_image()` is only called in `receive_layout()` (https://github.com/euske/pdfminer/blob/master/pdfminer/converter.py#L180), which in turn is called in `end_page()` (https://github.com/euske/pdfminer/blob/master/pdfminer/converter.py#L50), which in turn is called in `process_page()` (https://github.com/euske/pdfminer/blob/master/pdfminer/pdfinterp.py#L840).

Comment: This makes it pretty complicated. So my follow up questions; would you have any idea how I could return the files without forking pdfminer? And if not, would you have any pointers in how I could easily get the lists of images without having to edit a zillion lines of code?

Comment: Your problem is pdfminer creates the file on his side. If you don't have access to get the data the way you want it - you either save to a file and load that data later on, or change the API (fork). I'll think of a **hack** (which will always be just a hack) and if I come up with something I'll let you know...